# Django South problem in Aptana

Tags: django, aptana, django-south

I try to add `South` migration tool to my Django app. I installed `South` by running `python setup.py install` and it is installed successfully. Now I can run `migrate appname` and `schemamigration appname --auto` commands and they work great.

However, after I run `migration appname`, it created `migration` package under my app folder and created a `init.py`. There are such imports in this `init` file

```
import datetime
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import SchemaMigration
from django.db import models
```

Although everything works perfect, `from south.db` and  `from south.v2` lines give error in Aptana which is about it cannot import these files.

Do you have any idea why it happens ?  Should I add the location of south folder to any system  path ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the parent directory where south was installed (site-pacakges, or maybe a virtualenv's site-packages) folder to your Project's pythonpath?

You'll need to set your project as either a PyDev project or Django project.

Right-click on your project, choose the correct nature.
Then right-click again and go to Properties.
Choose the PyDev-PYTHONPATH setting and click on External Libraries.
Click Add source folder, nav to the parent of the module you want to add to the path and hit either apply or OK, depending on how many folders you want to add to the project's pythonpath.

Hope that helps you out.

Comment: Thanks that works for import problem but know it gives error for `db.create_table` lines in 0001_initial.py file and other migration files which south generates. Imported libraries are                 from south.db import db
from south.v2 import SchemaMigration

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure what might be going on with the imports not resolving in the migrations.